# Why not connect PHP imap/pop3?

Tags: php, imap, pop3, imap-open

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

Some days try, try and try. Read all stackoverflow questions and answers this, but no help.

I would like only one imap connection.

I try some webhost and not works.

Please help me.

```
// $foo = "{pop3.indamail.hu:110}"; // [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
// $foo = "{pop3.indamail.hu:110/pop3}"; // Can not authenticate to POP3 server: POP3 connection broken in response
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143}"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143/imap}"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{pop3.indamail.hu:110/pop3}INBOX"; // Can not authenticate to POP3 server: POP3 connection broken in response
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143/imap}INBOX"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143/imap/tls}INBOX"; // Unable to negotiate TLS with this server
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143/imap/notls}INBOX"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:993/imap}"; // [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
// $foo = "{pop3.indamail.hu:995/pop3}"; // POP3 connection broken in response
// $foo = "{imap.indamail.hu:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}"; // Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
// $foo = "{pop3.indamail.hu:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}"; // Can not authenticate to POP3 server: POP3 connection broken in response
$mbox = imap_open ( $foo, "********@indamail.hu", "********" ) or die ( imap_last_error () );
```

The errors, please see the code.

I try, but ok-ok:

```
// $fp = fsockopen ( "imap.indamail.hu", 143, $errno, $errstr, 30 ); // ok
// $fp = fsockopen ( "imap.indamail.hu", 993, $errno, $errstr, 30 ); // ok
// $fp = fsockopen ( "pop3.indamail.hu", 110, $errno, $errstr, 30 ); // ok
// $fp = fsockopen ( "pop3.indamail.hu", 995, $errno, $errstr, 30 ); // ok

// $fp = fsockopen ( "imap.indamail.hu", 992, $errno, $errstr, 30 ); // Connection timed out (110)

if ( ! $fp ) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
} else {
    echo "ok";
    fclose ( $fp );
}
```

Important! Only access countries: HU, SK, AT, RO, HR. My IP-address is HU/Hungary. I read the manual and I think only this ports: pop3:110 and imap:143.

Please help me.

Comment: When entering the password, it is not necessary to enter the login password, but the POP3 / IMAP password (information from their website). Are you using it correctly?

Comment: Now, most sites require encrypted pop3 (port 995) or IMAP (port 993)

Comment: @MartinOsusky Yes, I am using it correctly. I know. The webmail password is different from the pop3/imap password.

Comment: @Max I edited the question with several tests. No works 993/995 ports.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
$e = '********@indamail.hu';
$s = '{imap.indamail.hu:143/authuser=' . $e . '}';
$mbox = imap_open ( $s, $e, '********' ) or die ( imap_last_error () );
```

No comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think `POP3 connection broken in response` means a temporary connection failure.

Why do I think this?

Because I've been debugging a POP3 client program. After I hit the POP3 server at my hosting provider several times in succession, I think they lock me out. It's possible also that I try to take more than one concurrent exclusive-lock on my mailbox.

I think this message comes from within php-imap. I think it announces to the one calling `imap_login()` that the POP3 server stalled the tcp connection during authentication, then closed it abruptly.  That's a reasonable DOS-attack countermeasure. I must have triggered it by mistake while debugging.

After a while everything starts working again.

This POP3 is an ancient protocol. [RFC1939](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt) says that it has just two status messages, `+OK some random text` and `-ERR some other random text`.  So the content of those `imap_errors()` strings is whatever the programmer thought was helpful that day. Sigh.